# Ajv JSONSchemaType error using typescript

Tags: typescript, ajv

I'm having an issue writing a validator with Ajv and typescript.

Here is the definition of my schema

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";
const ajv = new Ajv();

interface Attribute {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  ref?: boolean;
  cardinality?: string;
  optional?: boolean;
}

interface Concept {
  type: string;
  root?: boolean;
  attributes?: Array<Attribute>;
  hidden?: boolean;
  terminal?: boolean;
  expression?: string;
}

const properties = {
  name: { type: "string" },
  type: { type: "string" },
  ref: { type: "boolean" },
  cardinality: { type: "string"}, 
  optional: { type: "boolean" },
};

const conceptSchema: JSONSchemaType<Concept> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    type: { type: "string" },
    root: { type: "boolean"},
    attributes: {
      type: "array",
      uniqueItems: true,
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: properties,
        required: ["name", "type"],
      },
    },
    hidden: { type: "boolean" },
    terminal: { type: "boolean" },
    expression: { type: "string" },
  },
  required: ["type"],
  additionalProperties: false,
};
```

Any idea why I'm getting the following error using ajv and typescript?

> "message": "Type '{ type: "object"; properties: { type: { type:
> "string"; }; root: { type: "boolean"; }; attributes: { type:
> "array"; uniqueItems: true; items: { type: "object"; properties: {
> name: { type: string; }; type: { type: string; }; ref: { ...; };
> cardinality: { ...; }; optional: { ...; }; }; required: ("type" |
> "name")[]; }...' is not assignable to type
> 'UncheckedJSONSchemaType<Concept, false>'.\n  The types of
> 'properties.attributes' are incompatible between these types.\n
> Type '{ type: "array"; uniqueItems: true; items: { type: "object";
> properties: { name: { type: string; }; type: { type: string; }; ref: {
> type: string; }; cardinality: { type: string; pattern: string; };
> optional: { type: string; }; }; required: ("type" | "name")[]; };
> }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } |
> (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<Attribute[] | undefined, false> & { nullable:
> true; const?: null | undefined; enum?: readonly (Attribute[] | null |
> undefined)[] | undefined; default?: Attribute[] | ... 1 more ... |
> undefined; })'.\n      Types of property 'items' are incompatible.\n
> Type '{ type: "object"; properties: { name: { type: string; }; type:
> { type: string; }; ref: { type: string; }; cardinality: { type:
> string; pattern: string; }; optional: { type: string; }; }; required:
> ("type" | "name")[]; }' is not assignable to type
> 'UncheckedJSONSchemaType<Attribute, false>'.\n          The types of
> 'properties.name' are incompatible between these types.\n
> Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; }
> | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<string, false> & { const?: string |
> undefined; enum?: readonly string[] | undefined; default?: string |
> undefined; })'.\n              Type '{ type: string; }' is not
> assignable to type '{ type: "string"; } & StringKeywords & { allOf?:
> readonly UncheckedPartialSchema[] | undefined; anyOf?:
> readonly UncheckedPartialSchema[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...;
> not?: UncheckedPartialSchema<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...;
> }'.\n                Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to
> type '{ type: "string"; }'.\n                  Types of property
> 'type' are incompatible.\n                    Type 'string' is not
> assignable to type '"string"'.",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your interface says that some properties can be undefined, you have to add that into your schema as `nullable: true` -

```
const conceptSchema: JSONSchemaType<Concept> = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        type: { type: "string" },
        root: { type: "boolean", nullable: true },
        attributes: {
            type: "array",
            uniqueItems: true,
            items: {
                type: "object",
                properties: {
                    name: { type: "string" },
                    type: { type: "string" },
                    ref: { type: "boolean", nullable: true },
                    cardinality: { type: "string", nullable: true },
                    optional: { type: "boolean", nullable: true },
                },
                required: ["name", "type"],
            },
            nullable: true,
        },
        hidden: { type: "boolean", nullable: true },
        terminal: { type: "boolean", nullable: true },
        expression: { type: "string", nullable: true },
    },
    required: ["type"],
    additionalProperties: false,
};
```

Also note that I have inlined the constant `properties` so it won't be inferred incorrectly.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w17oKm)